# How to Add Multiple Pickup Address

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex, address, ups

I have two stores, one from San San Antonio and another one Detroit. I will get the details from the customer,

[image]

I am using FedEx and UPS,

Supposed user select San Antonio, San Antonio based shipping charges display to the customer (This my current process) if customer select Detroit, Detroit based shipping charges display to the customer(Need to configure).

My one of the store running in San Antonio, so shipping charge display to the customer.

My another store will be open on next month in Detroit, so how can display shipping charge based on Detroit, because my pickup point Detroit(By Default my store display San Antonio based pickup charge to customer )

How can I add two pickup address charges method to the customer, `if customer select San Antonio, display San Antonio based shipping charge (current process working fine), also how can I display  Detroit pickup shipping charges to the customer?`

[image]

> How can I configure more than one pick up address?

Answer (score 0):

I use Owebia Shipping (https://marketplace.magento.com/owebia-owebia-shipping-2.html)

Not quite to do exactly this but something similar
I can call on custom fields and show only certain shipping methods/costs.
Maybe have a look at the documentation (https://owebia.com/os2/en/doc) before you install it to make sure you can configure it as necessary

Its extremely versatile so i'm sure you can use it to get to where you want to

Comment: Is possible can i integrate FedEx Shipping calculation by this one.

Comment: @Rathinam Possibly, I've had a quick look on their site and this module add-on could help maybe? (https://en.store.owebia.com/magento1-module-adv-ship-universal-setting-addon.html) This answer could also help? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20764817/2772911)